# Generate and store many images at first launch iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, image, colors

I need to generate and save 320 images as PNGs when the game is first run. These images will then be loaded instead of being generated again. Here is the process:

- load image template (black and white with alpha)
- overlay non transparent pixels with specified colour
- put on top the template at 0.3 opacity merging it to one final image
- return back UIImage
- store the UIImage, converted to NSData to PNG in Cache directory

This is done using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. This process needs to be done for 32 image templates in 10 colours **on the background thread**. The purpose is that these will be used as avatar/profile images in this game, scaled down at certain screens as appropriate. They cannot be generated every time though, because this causes too much lag.

The images are 400x400 each. They result being about 20/25 kB each when stored. When I try to use my current way of generating and storing, I get a memory warning and I see (using Instruments) that the number of alive CGImage and UIImage objects keeps increasing rapidly. This seems like they're being retained but I don't hold any references to them.

Here is my other question closer detailing the code I'm using: [UIGraphicsBeginImageContext created image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263533/uigraphicsbeginimagecontext-created-image-stays-in-memory-forever)

What is the **best** way to create and store to secondary storage this many images? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here's the whole code I currently use to create and save the images:

```c
//==========================================================
// Definitions and Macros
//==========================================================

//HEX color macro
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

//Colours
#define RED_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0xF65D58)
#define ORANGE_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0xFF8D16)
#define YELLOW_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0xFFD100)
#define LIGHT_GREEN_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x82DE13)
#define DARK_GREEN_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x67B74F)
#define TURQUOISE_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x32ADA6)
#define LIGHT_BLUE_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x11C9FF)
#define DARK_BLUE_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x2E97F5)
#define PURPLE_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0x8F73FD)
#define PINK_COLOUR UIColorFromRGB(0xF35991)



#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Generate the graphics
    [self generateAndSaveGraphics];

}




//==========================================================
// Generating and Saving Graphics
//==========================================================

-(void)generateAndSaveGraphics {

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self createAvatarImages];

        //Here create all other images that need to be saved to Cache directory


        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //Finished

            NSLog(@"DONE"); //always runs out of memory before getting here
        });

    });
}

-(void)createAvatarImages {

    //Create avatar images
    NSArray *colours = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:RED_COLOUR, ORANGE_COLOUR, YELLOW_COLOUR, LIGHT_GREEN_COLOUR, DARK_GREEN_COLOUR, TURQUOISE_COLOUR, LIGHT_BLUE_COLOUR, DARK_BLUE_COLOUR, PURPLE_COLOUR, PINK_COLOUR, nil];

    NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];


    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) { //Avatar image templates are named m1 - m16 and f1 - f16

        NSString *avatarImageName;

        if(i < 16) { //female avatars

            avatarImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%i", i+1];
        }
        else { //male avatars

            avatarImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"m%i", i-15];
        }


        for(int j = 0; j < colours.count; j++) { //make avatar image for each colour

            @autoreleasepool { //only helps very slightly

                UIColor *colour = [colours objectAtIndex:j];
                UIImage *avatarImage = [self tintedImageFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:avatarImageName] colour:colour intensity:0.3];

                NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%i.png", avatarImageName, j];
                NSString *filePath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(avatarImage)];
                [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

                NSLog(@"AVATAR IMAGE CREATED");

            }

        }
    }
}




//==========================================================
// Universal Image Tinting Code
//==========================================================

//Creates a tinted image based on the source greyscale image and tinting intensity
-(UIImage *)tintedImageFromImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage colour:(UIColor *)color intensity:(float)intensity {

    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sourceImage.size, NO, 0.0);

    } else {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sourceImage.size);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height);

    // draw alpha-mask
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage);

    // draw tint color, preserving alpha values of original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);


    //Set the original greyscale template as the overlay of the new image
    sourceImage = [self verticallyFlipImage:sourceImage];
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, sourceImage.size.width,sourceImage.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeMultiply alpha:intensity];

    UIImage *colouredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    colouredImage = [self verticallyFlipImage:colouredImage];


    return colouredImage;
}

//Vertically flips an image
-(UIImage *)verticallyFlipImage:(UIImage *)originalImage {

    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, tempImageView.frame.size.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

    [tempImageView.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *flippedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    return flippedImage;
}

@end
```

I've created a test project (in the zip) to illustrate the problem:

[Project Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r67i7x934gsp6fu/AvatarCreationTest.zip)

**For future reference, the solution is this one line of code:**

```
tempImageView.image = nil;
```

Thanks to Matic.

Comment: You didn't post any code but considering what you wrote it might be a problem with autorelease pool: If you use a "for" loop you should create internal autorelease pool inside the loop and drain it each cycle to ensure the release of those objects inside.

Comment: I tried wrapping the inside of the for loop in @autorelease {} but it didn't help. Is there anything I need to add to drain it? I thought it was automatic. Thanks

Comment: I normally allocate the autorelease pool and then drain it but I think this should do the same.. It is automatic but it will not simply brake your code and release the objects pushed to autorelease pool unless you specify so. It seems something is retaining the images anyway.. If possible (and nothing else works), try to subclass the UIImage and override the retain and release methods to see what object retains them. Also are you using ARC? Would it be possible to see some relevant code?

Comment: ..not those methodes to tint and flip the image (those look fine), the code with the "for" loop and autorelease pools might help.

Comment: I'll update the question with the code for the loop in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have added the code and the test project that fully illustrates the problem. I really need to sort this out.

Comment: I can't spot anything that might produce the leak, though there is one thing: You are using imageNamed which caches the images and they remain in memory until you receive memory warning. This is only 32 images though..

Comment: I've tried replacing imageNamed with imageWithContentsOfFile but it behaves exactly the same. Could it be this: UIImage *colouredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the issue is in method `verticallyFlipImage`. The graphics context seems to retain the temporary image view you create and with it the image you assign. This issue would probably be generally fixed by pushing each image through the process as its own dispatch call: Resample image -> callback -> resample next (or exit).

In the end of the whole resampling all the data is released and there is no memory leak. To make a quick fix you can simply call `tempImageView.image = nil;` before returning the image. The image view itself still produces a memory inflate but it is too small to have any impact.

This works for me and I hope it helps you.

**EDIT:** added the dispatch concept (comment reference)

```
dispatch_queue_t internalQueue;
- (void)createQueue {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void) {
        internalQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); //we created a high priority queue
    });
}
- (void)deleteQueue {
    dispatch_release(internalQueue);
}
- (void)imageProcessingDone {
    [self deleteQueue];
    //all done here
}
- (void)processImagesInArray:(NSMutableArray *)imageArray {
    //take out 1 of the objects (last in this case, you can do objectAtIndex:0 if you wish)
    UIImage *img = [[imageArray lastObject] retain]; //note, image retained so the next line does not deallocate it (released at NOTE1)
    [imageArray removeLastObject]; //remove from the array
    dispatch_async(internalQueue, ^(void) { //dispach

        //do all the image processing + saving

        [img release];//NOTE1

        //callback: In this case I push it the main thread. There should be little difference if you simply dispach it again on the internalQueue
        if(imageArray.count > 0) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processImagesInArray:) withObject:imageArray waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
        else {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageProcessingDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to fully optimize this by creating each image in each own dispatch call like you suggested. Strangely, I'm still left with 39 alive CGImages and 37 UIImages after it's all done. How can I get that to none? There's absolutely nothing that should be loaded.

Comment: After a lot of messing around, I'll go with the 'quick fix'. Making each image in its own dispatch call didn't make any difference at all. I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.. You should process all the images on the same queue but instead of calling a for loop you should process 1st image, get a callback when its done, dispatch another image, get a callback when its done, dispatch yet another image... Until all are resampled. If you just put every image in its own queue it will try to process all the images simultaneously which leads to extreme memory consumption.

Comment: I've created a recursive method that does exactly what you describe, it does one image, then calls itself again with the new image name in the callback. So I think this should only be doing one at a time. But there's still 39 CGImages and 37 UIImages at the end.

Comment: Strange, this should rather be bullet-proof.. Though I hope you did not do a straight recursion as this is the same or worse then the "for loop", you need to call dispatch async for each and every image to be processed.

Comment: I'm not sure. If it isn't too much trouble, could you show me a snippet for what you mean? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you! That's different from what I had. I'll implement this.